# Split the graph containing multiple records in Splunk

Tags: graph, charts, splunk

Hi everyone I have problem with visualising the graph with my data.

Here's my example that works fine because I guess the time range is the same (date + time) while my actual log data on Splunk is just the date.

```
| makeresults
| eval raw="10, 2, typeA, 2022-05-29T20:12:50.000-07:00|11, 3, typeB, 2022-05-29T15:10:26.000-07:00|5, 1, typeB, 2022-05-29T03:08:34.000-07:00"
| makemv raw delim="|"
| mvexpand raw
| rex field=raw "^(?<processed>[^,]+),(?<failed>[^,]+),(?<release>[^,]+),(?<_time>[^,]+)$"
| chart values(processed), values(failed) over _time by release
| bin span=1d _time
```

So in this example the "typeB" for the same date contains 2 values "11" and "5". When you go to visualise this graph (Column graph) it works fine, I see 2 columns with with values 11 & 5.
But in my actual data in Splunk when I run

```
| chart values(processed), values(failed) over _time by release
| bin span=1d _time
```

I'm getting only the date [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7DRa1.png) so the values overlap [overlapping screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6IRH.png) like so.

Any idea how to split this column into 2 (or more based on the number of values for that column)?

Edit: This is the _time from my data in Splunk [image: My data]

and this is the _time from the example data [image]

Answer (score 0):

I see a normal chart when I run your query.  Please tell us more about your environment.  Which version of Splunk?  What visualization settings?
[image]

Sorry for not putting this in a comment where it belongs, but I couldn't put the image in a comment.

Comment: yeah I know. when you run my example it works fine because it's using the full timestamp and when I run it on my actual data it's only using the date (without time) so I guess it doesn't know how to split the chart. I don't know how to replicate my actual data and how it splits based on _time

Comment: I updated the question with more screenshots